# How to extract a substring of a string when "unhashable type: 'slice'" from html parsed data

Tags: python, string, parsing, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_us.rss"

content = requests.get(url) #retrieve the html code as a string
print(content.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
tag = soup.find_all('description')
print(tag[1])
```

The following line is printed:

```
<description>The University of South Carolina accepted the resignation Wednesday of President Bob Caslen, who admitted he plagiarized part of a speech by the former head of US Special Operations Command during a weekend commencement speech.&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/rss/edition_us/~4/M9Jh7F8spxs" height="1" width="1" alt=""/&gt;</description>
```

I would like to retrieve the message:

```
The University of South Carolina accepted the resignation Wednesday of President Bob Caslen, who admitted he plagiarized part of a speech by the former head of US Special Operations Command during a weekend commencement speech.
```

I tried using `iloc` and `X.values`

Comment: Doesn't `tag.text` have everything you need?

Comment: [SOLVED] When using tag[1].text I get The University of South Carolina accepted the resignation Wednesday of President Bob Caslen, who admitted he plagiarized part of a speech by the former head of US Special Operations Command during a weekend commencement speech.<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/rss/edition_us/~4/M9Jh7F8spxs" height="1" width="1" alt=""/>.   Edit: you gave me an idea. I can iterate through the string